# packing predefined circles in a rectangle

Tags: d3.js

I was trying a d3.js code http://jsfiddle.net/TDzVE/ but this code works for random radii but according to algorithm or the way i want this to work is to use predefined radii like 10,15,20,30... How can I achieve that. Please help.

When I check the `radii` used by the code they are not what predefined `radii`, they are randomly generated `radii` or `radii` that are used optimally to reduce the area of rectangle.

```
// ===========================
// ancillary geometric classes
// ===========================
var Point = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
};

Point.prototype = {
  dist: function(p) {
    return this.vect(p).norm();
  },
  vect: function(p) {
    return new Point(p.x - this.x, p.y - this.y);
  },
  norm: function(p) {
    return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
  },
  add: function(v) {
    return new Point(this.x + v.x, this.y + v.y);
  },
  mult: function(a) {
    return new Point(this.x * a, this.y * a);
  }
};
var Circle = function(radius, center) {
  this.r = radius;
  this.c = center;
};

Circle.prototype = {
  surface: function() {
    return Math.PI * this.r * this.r;
  },
  distance: function(circle) {
    return this.c.dist(circle.c) - this.r - circle.r;
  }
};

// =========================
// circle packer lives here!
// =========================
var Packer = function(circles, ratio) {
  this.circles = circles;
  this.ratio = ratio || 1;
  this.list = this.solve();
};

Packer.prototype = {
  // try to fit all circles into a rectangle of a given surface
  compute: function(surface) {
    // check if a circle is inside our rectangle
    function in_rect(radius, center) {
      if (center.x - radius < -w / 2) return false;
      if (center.x + radius > w / 2) return false;
      if (center.y - radius < -h / 2) return false;
      if (center.y + radius > h / 2) return false;
      return true;
    }

    // approximate a segment with an "infinite" radius circle
    function bounding_circle(x0, y0, x1, y1) {
      var xm = Math.abs((x1 - x0) * w);
      var ym = Math.abs((y1 - y0) * h);
      var m = xm > ym ? xm : ym;
      var theta = Math.asin(m / 4 / bounding_r);
      var r = bounding_r * Math.cos(theta);
      return new Circle(
        bounding_r,
        new Point(
          (r * (y0 - y1)) / 2 + ((x0 + x1) * w) / 4,
          (r * (x1 - x0)) / 2 + ((y0 + y1) * h) / 4
        )
      );
    }

    // return the corner placements for two circles
    function corner(radius, c1, c2) {
      var u = c1.c.vect(c2.c); // c1 to c2 vector
      var A = u.norm();
      if (A == 0) return []; // same centers
      u = u.mult(1 / A); // c1 to c2 unary vector
      // compute c1 and c2 intersection coordinates in (u,v) base
      var B = c1.r + radius;
      var C = c2.r + radius;
      if (A > B + C) return []; // too far apart
      var x = (A + (B * B - C * C) / A) / 2;
      var y = Math.sqrt(B * B - x * x);
      var base = c1.c.add(u.mult(x));

      var res = [];
      var p1 = new Point(base.x - u.y * y, base.y + u.x * y);
      var p2 = new Point(base.x + u.y * y, base.y - u.x * y);
      if (in_rect(radius, p1)) res.push(new Circle(radius, p1));
      if (in_rect(radius, p2)) res.push(new Circle(radius, p2));
      return res;
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // deduce starting dimensions from surface
    var bounding_r = Math.sqrt(surface) * 100; // "infinite" radius
    var w = (this.w = Math.sqrt(surface * this.ratio));
    var h = (this.h = this.w / this.ratio);

    // place our bounding circles
    var placed = [
      bounding_circle(1, 1, 1, -1),
      bounding_circle(1, -1, -1, -1),
      bounding_circle(-1, -1, -1, 1),
      bounding_circle(-1, 1, 1, 1)
    ];

    // Initialize our rectangles list
    var unplaced = this.circles.slice(0); // clones the array
    while (unplaced.length > 0) {
      // compute all possible placements of the unplaced circles
      var lambda = {};
      var circle = {};
      for (var i = 0; i != unplaced.length; i++) {
        var lambda_min = 1e10;
        lambda[i] = -1e10;
        // match current circle against all possible pairs of placed circles
        for (var j = 0; j < placed.length; j++)
          for (var k = j + 1; k < placed.length; k++) {
            // find corner placement
            if (k > 3) {
              zog = 1;
            }
            var corners = corner(unplaced[i], placed[j], placed[k]);

            // check each placement
            for (var c = 0; c != corners.length; c++) {
              // check for overlap and compute min distance
              var d_min = 1e10;
              for (var l = 0; l != placed.length; l++) {
                // skip the two circles used for the placement
                if (l == j || l == k) continue;

                // compute distance from current circle
                var d = placed[l].distance(corners[c]);
                if (d < 0) break; // circles overlap

                if (d < d_min) d_min = d;
              }
              if (l == placed.length) {
                // no overlap
                if (d_min < lambda_min) {
                  lambda_min = d_min;
                  lambda[i] = 1 - d_min / unplaced[i];
                  circle[i] = corners[c];
                }
              }
            }
          }
      }

      // select the circle with maximal gain
      var lambda_max = -1e10;
      var i_max = -1;
      for (var i = 0; i != unplaced.length; i++) {
        if (lambda[i] > lambda_max) {
          lambda_max = lambda[i];
          i_max = i;
        }
      }

      // failure if no circle fits
      if (i_max == -1) break;

      // place the selected circle
      unplaced.splice(i_max, 1);
      placed.push(circle[i_max]);
    }

    // return all placed circles except the four bounding circles
    this.tmp_bounds = placed.splice(0, 4);
    return placed;
  },

  // find the smallest rectangle to fit all circles
  solve: function() {
    // compute total surface of the circles
    var surface = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i != this.circles.length; i++) {
      surface += Math.PI * Math.pow(this.circles[i], 2);
    }

    // set a suitable precision
    var limit = surface / 1000;

    var step = surface / 2;
    var res = [];
    while (step > limit) {
      var placement = this.compute.call(this, surface);
      console.log(
        "placed",
        placement.length,
        "out of",
        this.circles.length,
        "for surface",
        surface
      );
      if (placement.length != this.circles.length) {
        surface += step;
      } else {
        res = placement;
        this.bounds = this.tmp_bounds;
        surface -= step;
      }
      step /= 2;
    }
    return res;
  }
};

// ====
// demo
// ====
function draw_result(packer) {
  function draw_circle(circle) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(
      (circle.c.x + dx) * zoom + mx,
      (circle.c.y + dy) * zoom + my,
      circle.r * zoom,
      0,
      2 * Math.PI
    );
    m = circle.r;
    //console.log("radius",m);

    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width += 0; // clear canvas
  var margin_factor = 0.1;

  var mx = (canvas.width * margin_factor) / 2;
  var my = (canvas.height * margin_factor) / 2;
  var dx = packer.w / 2;
  var dy = packer.h / 2;
  var zx = (canvas.width * (1 - margin_factor)) / packer.w;
  var zy = (canvas.height * (1 - margin_factor)) / packer.h;
  var zoom = zx < zy ? zx : zy;

  // draw all circles
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  for (var i = 0; i != packer.list.length; i++) draw_circle(packer.list[i]);
  v = packer.list;
  console.log("circles", v);

  // draw bounding circles
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  for (var i = 0; i != packer.bounds.length; i++) draw_circle(packer.bounds[i]);

  // draw rectangle
  ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(
    (-packer.w / 2 + dx) * zoom + mx,
    (-packer.h / 2 + dy) * zoom + my,
    packer.w * zoom,
    packer.h * zoom
  );
  let a = packer.w * zoom;
  let b = packer.h * zoom;
  console.log("width", a, "length", b);

  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
}

function draw() {
  var circles = parseInt(document.getElementById("c").value);
  var ratio = parseFloat(document.getElementById("r").value);
  var min_r = parseInt(document.getElementById("a").value);
  var max_r = parseInt(document.getElementById("b").value);
  var radiuses = [];
  for (var i = 0; i != circles; i++)
    radiuses.push(Math.random() * (max_r - min_r) + min_r);
  var packer = new Packer(radiuses, ratio);
  draw_result(packer);
}

window.onload = draw;
```

Comment: I believe  you should remove your Math.random() in the last bit of code and do something to put in your predefined radii here. Either have an  array that you take it from or basenumber that you then add i * 5 to and send that in place of the Math.random()

Answer (score 1):

If I got what you want right, just comment-out the `for()` loop and replace it with hard-coded value for the array `radiuses` like this:

```
function draw() {
  var circles = 10; //parseInt  (document.getElementById('c').value);
  var ratio = 1; //parseFloat(document.getElementById('r').value);
  var min_r = 1; //parseInt  (document.getElementById('a').value);
  var max_r = 10; //parseInt  (document.getElementById('b').value);

  console.log(circles, ratio, min_r, max_r);
  var radiuses = [];
  // for (var i = 0 ; i != circles ; i++)
  // radiuses.push (Math.random() * (max_r-min_r) + min_r);
  radiuses = [
    3.9583054608672303,
    5.108187765437406,
    5.8970449014304505,
    6.176802256787828,
    2.875371765313655,
    8.017411283036802,
    8.751854615569854,
    2.7833816354701018,
    2.408464192175587,
    3.8428318045023144
  ];
  var packer = new Packer(radiuses, ratio);
  draw_result(packer);
}
```

Also not that we just hard-coded the number of the circles along with form controls for other parameters values `circles`, `ratio`, `min_r` `max_r`

and here is working snippet:

```js
// ===========================
// ancillary geometric classes
// ===========================
var Point = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
};

Point.prototype = {
  dist: function(p) {
    return this.vect(p).norm();
  },
  vect: function(p) {
    return new Point(p.x - this.x, p.y - this.y);
  },
  norm: function(p) {
    return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
  },
  add: function(v) {
    return new Point(this.x + v.x, this.y + v.y);
  },
  mult: function(a) {
    return new Point(this.x * a, this.y * a);
  }
};
var Circle = function(radius, center) {
  this.r = radius;
  this.c = center;
};

Circle.prototype = {
  surface: function() {
    return Math.PI * this.r * this.r;
  },
  distance: function(circle) {
    return this.c.dist(circle.c) - this.r - circle.r;
  }
};

// =========================
// circle packer lives here!
// =========================
var Packer = function(circles, ratio) {
  this.circles = circles;
  this.ratio = ratio || 1;
  this.list = this.solve();
};

Packer.prototype = {
  // try to fit all circles into a rectangle of a given surface
  compute: function(surface) {
    // check if a circle is inside our rectangle
    function in_rect(radius, center) {
      if (center.x - radius < -w / 2) return false;
      if (center.x + radius > w / 2) return false;
      if (center.y - radius < -h / 2) return false;
      if (center.y + radius > h / 2) return false;
      return true;
    }

    // approximate a segment with an "infinite" radius circle
    function bounding_circle(x0, y0, x1, y1) {
      var xm = Math.abs((x1 - x0) * w);
      var ym = Math.abs((y1 - y0) * h);
      var m = xm > ym ? xm : ym;
      var theta = Math.asin(m / 4 / bounding_r);
      var r = bounding_r * Math.cos(theta);
      return new Circle(
        bounding_r,
        new Point(
          (r * (y0 - y1)) / 2 + ((x0 + x1) * w) / 4,
          (r * (x1 - x0)) / 2 + ((y0 + y1) * h) / 4
        )
      );
    }

    // return the corner placements for two circles
    function corner(radius, c1, c2) {
      var u = c1.c.vect(c2.c); // c1 to c2 vector
      var A = u.norm();
      if (A == 0) return []; // same centers
      u = u.mult(1 / A); // c1 to c2 unary vector
      // compute c1 and c2 intersection coordinates in (u,v) base
      var B = c1.r + radius;
      var C = c2.r + radius;
      if (A > B + C) return []; // too far apart
      var x = (A + (B * B - C * C) / A) / 2;
      var y = Math.sqrt(B * B - x * x);
      var base = c1.c.add(u.mult(x));

      var res = [];
      var p1 = new Point(base.x - u.y * y, base.y + u.x * y);
      var p2 = new Point(base.x + u.y * y, base.y - u.x * y);
      if (in_rect(radius, p1)) res.push(new Circle(radius, p1));
      if (in_rect(radius, p2)) res.push(new Circle(radius, p2));
      return res;
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // deduce starting dimensions from surface
    var bounding_r = Math.sqrt(surface) * 100; // "infinite" radius
    var w = (this.w = Math.sqrt(surface * this.ratio));
    var h = (this.h = this.w / this.ratio);

    // place our bounding circles
    var placed = [
      bounding_circle(1, 1, 1, -1),
      bounding_circle(1, -1, -1, -1),
      bounding_circle(-1, -1, -1, 1),
      bounding_circle(-1, 1, 1, 1)
    ];

    // Initialize our rectangles list
    var unplaced = this.circles.slice(0); // clones the array
    while (unplaced.length > 0) {
      // compute all possible placements of the unplaced circles
      var lambda = {};
      var circle = {};
      for (var i = 0; i != unplaced.length; i++) {
        var lambda_min = 1e10;
        lambda[i] = -1e10;
        // match current circle against all possible pairs of placed circles
        for (var j = 0; j < placed.length; j++)
          for (var k = j + 1; k < placed.length; k++) {
            // find corner placement
            if (k > 3) {
              zog = 1;
            }
            var corners = corner(unplaced[i], placed[j], placed[k]);

            // check each placement
            for (var c = 0; c != corners.length; c++) {
              // check for overlap and compute min distance
              var d_min = 1e10;
              for (var l = 0; l != placed.length; l++) {
                // skip the two circles used for the placement
                if (l == j || l == k) continue;

                // compute distance from current circle
                var d = placed[l].distance(corners[c]);
                if (d < 0) break; // circles overlap

                if (d < d_min) d_min = d;
              }
              if (l == placed.length) {
                // no overlap
                if (d_min < lambda_min) {
                  lambda_min = d_min;
                  lambda[i] = 1 - d_min / unplaced[i];
                  circle[i] = corners[c];
                }
              }
            }
          }
      }

      // select the circle with maximal gain
      var lambda_max = -1e10;
      var i_max = -1;
      for (var i = 0; i != unplaced.length; i++) {
        if (lambda[i] > lambda_max) {
          lambda_max = lambda[i];
          i_max = i;
        }
      }

      // failure if no circle fits
      if (i_max == -1) break;

      // place the selected circle
      unplaced.splice(i_max, 1);
      placed.push(circle[i_max]);
    }

    // return all placed circles except the four bounding circles
    this.tmp_bounds = placed.splice(0, 4);
    return placed;
  },

  // find the smallest rectangle to fit all circles
  solve: function() {
    // compute total surface of the circles
    var surface = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i != this.circles.length; i++) {
      surface += Math.PI * Math.pow(this.circles[i], 2);
    }

    // set a suitable precision
    var limit = surface / 1000;

    var step = surface / 2;
    var res = [];
    while (step > limit) {
      var placement = this.compute.call(this, surface);
      if (placement.length != this.circles.length) {
        surface += step;
      } else {
        res = placement;
        this.bounds = this.tmp_bounds;
        surface -= step;
      }
      step /= 2;
    }
    return res;
  }
};

// ====
// demo
// ====
function draw_result(packer) {
  function draw_circle(circle) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(
      (circle.c.x + dx) * zoom + mx,
      (circle.c.y + dy) * zoom + my,
      circle.r * zoom,
      0,
      2 * Math.PI
    );
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width += 0; // clear canvas
  var margin_factor = 0.1;

  var mx = (canvas.width * margin_factor) / 2;
  var my = (canvas.height * margin_factor) / 2;
  var dx = packer.w / 2;
  var dy = packer.h / 2;
  var zx = (canvas.width * (1 - margin_factor)) / packer.w;
  var zy = (canvas.height * (1 - margin_factor)) / packer.h;
  var zoom = zx < zy ? zx : zy;

  // draw all circles
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  for (var i = 0; i != packer.list.length; i++) draw_circle(packer.list[i]);

  // draw bounding circles
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  for (var i = 0; i != packer.bounds.length; i++) draw_circle(packer.bounds[i]);

  // draw rectangle
  ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(
    (-packer.w / 2 + dx) * zoom + mx,
    (-packer.h / 2 + dy) * zoom + my,
    packer.w * zoom,
    packer.h * zoom
  );
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
}

function draw() {
  var circles = parseInt(document.getElementById("c").value);
  var ratio = parseFloat(document.getElementById("r").value);
  var min_r = parseInt(document.getElementById("a").value);
  var max_r = parseInt(document.getElementById("b").value);
  var radiuses = [];
  // for (var i = 0 ; i != circles ; i++)
  // radiuses.push (Math.random() * (max_r-min_r) + min_r);
  radiuses = [
    3.9583054608672303,
    5.108187765437406,
    5.8970449014304505,
    6.176802256787828,
    2.875371765313655,
    8.017411283036802,
    8.751854615569854,
    2.7833816354701018,
    2.408464192175587,
    3.8428318045023144
  ];
  var packer = new Packer(radiuses, ratio);
  draw_result(packer);
}

window.onload = draw;
```

```html
        <canvas id='canvas' width='400' height='400'></canvas>
<div>
<label>Circles   <input id='c' type='range' value='10' min='1'  max='100' step='1'></label><br />
<label>Ratio     <input id='r' type='range' value='1'  min='.5' max='1.5' step='0.1'></label><br />
<label>min radius<input id='a' type='range' value='1'  min='1' max='20'   step='1'></label><br />
<label>max radius<input id='b' type='range' value='10' min='1' max='20'   step='1'></label>
</div>
<button onclick='draw()'>Draw</button>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. but now only radii that are in array are used like if I put 10 radii in array than only 10 circles are drawn, but i want to randomly select from these 10 radii again and again till total no. of circles limit is reached.

Comment: not sure I got your issue, can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: radiuses array contain 10 radii radiuses = [
    3.9583054608672303,
    5.108187765437406,
   ..... ] ,now only 10 circles are drawn but i want to draw more circles by randomly selecting radii from this array.

Comment: I just tried this thing and it worked to select items many times randomly from an array.                                                                                                                    
    var radius = [10,15,20,25,30,35,40];
    var radiuses=[];
    for (var i = 0 ; i != circles ; i++){
    radiuses.push(radius[Math.floor(Math.random() * (radius.length -1))]);
    }

Comment: Hi @ritikasharma, should I add it to my answer?